# Is there a way to filter a DataFrame by unique variables stored in another DataFrame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to filter a list of nested dataframes based on variables in another dataframe, and create a new dataframe for each grouping variable after the filter is applied.

Sample dataset and group

```
combined <- data.frame(
  client = c('aaa','aaa','aaa','bbb','bbb','ccc','ccc','ddd','ddd'),
  type = c('norm','reg','opt','norm','norm','reg','opt','opt','opt'),
  age = c('>50','>50','75+','<25','<25','>50','75+','25-50','25-50'),
  IsActive = c('1','0','0','1','1','0','1','1','1')
)

# get unique variable combinations
unique_vars <- combined %>% 
  distinct() %>%
  group_split(client)
```

I think the variable combinations in `unique_vars` could be applied to the original dataframe `combined` to create individual dataframes based on the unique variables for each client.  the output I am looking to create is a dataframe for each combination of variables for each client in the original dataframe and their unique variables.  So as example there would be 3 dataframes created for client "aaa" based upon `unique_vars[1]` but only 1 dataframe created for client "ddd" based upon `unique_vars[4]` since there is only one row of possible variable combinations for client "ddd"

Any advice on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the `distinct` command from `dplyr`

`split(distinct(combined),row.names(distinct(combined)))`

gives

```
$`1`
  client type age IsActive
1    aaa norm >50        1

$`2`
  client type age IsActive
2    aaa  reg >50        0

$`3`
  client type age IsActive
3    aaa  opt 75+        0

$`4`
  client type age IsActive
4    bbb norm <25        1

$`5`
  client type age IsActive
5    ccc  reg >50        0

$`6`
  client type age IsActive
6    ccc  opt 75+        1

$`7`
  client type   age IsActive
7    ddd  opt 25-50        1
```

Answer (score 1):

One option involving `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
map(.x = combined %>%
     distinct() %>%
     group_split(rowid = 1:n()),
    ~ combined %>%
     inner_join(.x))

[[1]]
  client type age IsActive rowid
1    aaa norm >50        1     1

[[2]]
  client type age IsActive rowid
1    aaa  reg >50        0     2

[[3]]
  client type age IsActive rowid
1    aaa  opt 75+        0     3

[[4]]
  client type age IsActive rowid
1    bbb norm <25        1     4
2    bbb norm <25        1     4

[[5]]
  client type age IsActive rowid
1    ccc  reg >50        0     5

[[6]]
  client type age IsActive rowid
1    ccc  opt 75+        1     6

[[7]]
  client type   age IsActive rowid
1    ddd  opt 25-50        1     7
2    ddd  opt 25-50        1     7
```

Comment: this worked perfectly and was a simple solution to my problem!